# Se pueden tener varios JFrame diferentes y guardarlos en un solo hashmap? Despues obtener sus métodos y atributos propios?

Tags: java

Esta es mi idea. Tengo dos JFrame `form_guardarDatos` y `form_mostrarDatos`. Quiero guardarlos en un hashMap y despues utilizar ese hashMap para invocarlos en una clase principal. Por ejemplo para obtener el dato a guardar invocando

```
mapa['keyGuardarDatos'].getDatoAGuardar().getText();
```

En este caso `getDatoAGuardar()` solo esta en `form_guardarDatos`.

Si no me equivoco en python podía pasar una clase como instancia y siempre obtener sus atributos y métodos dentro de una lista pero no se si esto sea posible en java puesto que para pasar un parámetro es necesario declarar el tipo igual a su clase.

Saludos y gracias por el apoyo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se puede. Resolví el problema trabajando algo parecido al modelo vista controlador. Cree una clase controlador donde inicia lizo los jframe y les paso esa misma clase por el constructor y dentro de los Frame mando a llamar las funciones que necesito.